# Why should all Glass.Mapper fields be virtual?

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

The [Glass.Mapper documentation states](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial2):

> ```
> using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
>
> namespace Glass.Mapper.Sites.Sc.Models.Landing
> {
>     public class HomePage
>     {
>         public virtual string Title { get; set; }
>         public virtual string MainBody { get; set; }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You can see that this class doesn't include any special markup however
>   one important thing to remember when writing class with Glass.Mapper
>   is to ensure that all your **fields are marked as virtual**. Glass.Mapper
>   can automatically infer what data to load for your model by using a
>   combination of On Demand mapping and Auto-Mapping.

It eludes to use "On-demand" and "Auto-Mapping" but doesn't explain how or why.

Does anyone know why it's important to flag these fields as `virtual`? It seems to work perfectly fine without this. Nothing I can see inherits the fields and `overrides` them?

Comment: Those are properties, not fields.

Comment: I've left it as fields, as that is what the sitecore (incorrectly) call them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using lazy loading, Glass mapper needs to be able to dynamically generate a proxy class on the fly that wraps your class. To be able to inherit and override your properties, they need to be marked `virtual`.

Comment: Sitecore doesn't (that I'm aware of) support lazy loading though? Is this an Umbraco thing?

Comment: Glass does the lazy loading for you in the Sitecore implementation. At least as much as is possible in Sitecore.

Comment: I believe properties also need to be virtual in order to use [InferredTypes](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial17.aspx)